# Informix SQL / reuse result of stored procedure in another query

Tags: sql, informix

I want to use the result of stored procedure in another query. But I do not know the correct syntax. DBMS : IBM Informix, Stored procedure, I use.

```
Select col1 from table (MULTISET(EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure ('param1','param2')))
```

Comment: Informix 11.x (meaning 11.10, 11.50 or 11.70), I assume?  Version number is always worth noting; platform is worth noting too, though it is not going to be critical to this issue.

Comment: Version number is IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.UC5XE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SF_DYN_REP_EXEC(i_sql varchar)
    RETURNING INT, VARCHAR(30);

    DEFINE ret_groupid int;
    DEFINE ret_groupname varchar(30);
    FOREACH cursor1
    FOR
        SELECT groupid,
             groupname INTO 
             ret_groupid,
             ret_groupname
        FROM tctaddinmessagegroups
        RETURN ret_groupid,
             ret_groupname WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH;
END FUNCTION;

select vret_groupid C1,
             vret_groupname C2 from
table (function SF_DYN_REP_EXEC('blablabla'))
vtab1(vret_groupid,
             vret_groupname)
order by vret_groupid,
             vret_groupname;
```